# laravel updating editing database record - getting error when submitting the form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I am using this code to edit database record :

```
public function service_edit($id)
{
    $service = Service::find($id);
    return view('Super_Admin/service/.service_edit')->with('service', $service);
}

public function service_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $service = Service::find($id);
    $input['title_name'] = strtoupper ($request['title_name']);
    $input['link'] = strtoupper ($request['link']);
    $input['note'] = strtoupper ($request['note']);
    $input['image'] = time().'.'.$request->

    image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $folder1 = public_path('WEBSITE-FILE/SERVICE/1');
    $path1 = $folder1 . $input['image']; // path 1
    $request->image->move($folder1, $input['image']);
    $path2 = public_path('WEBSITE-FILE/SERVICE/2').$input['image'];// path 2
    $path3 = public_path('WEBSITE-FILE/SERVICE/3'). $input['image']; // path 3
    $path4 = public_path('WEBSITE-FILE/SERVICE/4'). $input['image']; // path 4

    \File::copy($path1, $path2);
    \File::copy($path1, $path3);
    \File::copy($path1, $path4);

    $service->save();

    return back()->with('success','UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

I am facing this error when I submit the form

> "Call to a member function save() on array"

Comment: `$service` is where you have to save, not `$input`

Comment: @porloscerros i changed that code, form submitted successful but record not updated in database

Comment: I wrote an answer. You must to assign the values ​​of the request to the $service variable (Service Model) and then save it.

Comment: You are not updating any column in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$service` is where you have to save, not `$input`.
You must to assign the values ​​of the request to the $service variable (Service Object) and then save it.
Try in this way:

```
public function service_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $service = Service::find($id);
    $service->title_name = strtoupper ($request->title_name);
    $service->link = strtoupper ($request->link);
    $service->note = strtoupper ($request->note);
    $service->image = time().'.'.$request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // ...

    $service->save();

    return back()->with('success','UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY .');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `$input` as an array, then you call `$input->save()`,  that's why the error is raised.

Maybe you wanted to use `$service` in place of `$input` ?

Comment: i tried this but data not updated in database, and also not showing error

Comment: You haven't tried correctly, because I suggested the same answer of @porloscerros . Glad that it helped you though

Answer (score 0):

change the following line and try

```
$input= Service::find($id);
```

Comment: i changed that code, form submitted successful but record not updated in database